# Google analytics is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-analytics

Google analytics is not working in my proj env.
Url is http://gtz-proj-cr.cloudapp.net/CR2

**tracking Code**

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
  i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g;    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', trackingID, trackingDomain);
    })();
```

Finally on any event click I am calling following code:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'event Name');
```

Similarly I am also sending pageview data but nothing get recorded in Analytics tool.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Double check your implementation of the GA code, it seems like you have the beginning portion of the UA code however when it is supposed to declare the account and send a page view it is not doing that properly and still has some classic analytics code. The event you are sending should work once the other tracking is set up however I did not see it being implemented on any of the links (I did only view the log in screen).

Comment: @Rayan My Application is a Single-Page-Application using Durandal and Knockout in which I am sending the "pageview" while navigating from one page to another and for event tracking I am using `ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'event Name');`. All these working fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the option "Do not track" in Internet Explorer 11. Somehow visitors won't reach the succespage they should be redirected to in order to track the convesion.

https://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Enable-or-Disable-Do-Not-Track-in-Internet-Explorer-10-307811.shtml